# Why I can't delete column without another column existed from this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

Tables:

```
projects - id, id_users
categories - id, id_project, id_users
marks - id, id_project, id_category, id_users
```

I have this SQL:

```
DELETE projects, categories, marks FROM projects
LEFT JOIN categories ON projects.id=categories.id_project AND projects.id_users=categories.id_users
LEFT JOIN marks ON categories.id=marks.id_category AND categories.id_project=marks.id_project AND categories.id_users=marks.id_users
WHERE projects.id=:id AND categories.id_users=:id_users
```

If category column, whitch is depending on project column, exist, then project can be deleted.. but, if category column, whitch is depending on projects column, doesn't exist, it can't be deleted. So I'm asking, why ? what I do wrong ?

Comment: from which table you want to delete data and what is referential integrity set in your tables..if there on delete cascade update...

Answer (score 1):

Multiple-table DELETE statements can be written in two formats. The following example
demonstrates one syntax, for a query that deletes rows from a table t1 where the id values
match those in a table t2:

```
DELETE t1 FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

The second syntax is slightly different:

```
DELETE FROM t1 USING t1, t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

To delete the matching records from both tables, the statements are:

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
DELETE FROM t1, t2 USING t1, t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

The ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses normally supported by UPDATE and DELETE aren’t allowed
when these statements are used for multiple-table operations.

Comment: thanks, but this all I know and have no problem with deleting from 2 tables, but I have 3 tables and "project" can't be deleted, if have no category..

Answer (score 0):

As per your table structure 'project' table is the master of 'categories' and 'marks' tables. And 'categories' is master of 'marks' tables. If you are using innodb engine then just keep delete cascade property on in your foreign keys.

By this you just need to delete data from your master table called project and data will be deleted automatically from all its child tables. This delete query will be light.

But if you are using myisam engine then you can go with your idea.

Comment: yeah, I'm using MyISAM and I just realized that my first attempt was uselessly complicated.. I start thinking about how it works, and then I made this second query, whitch is exactly what I was looking for..

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> EDIT: I got it..
>
> ```
> DELETE projects, categories, marks FROM projects
> LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id_project=projects.id
> LEFT JOIN marks ON marks.id_project=projects.id
> WHERE projects.id=:id AND projects.id_users=:id_users
> ```

Comment: ([Answered in an edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).)